# How to Not fetch screenshots from Photos library iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, photokit

I am trying to fetch Photos from Photo library and I want to show only images from the Photo Library. I do not want to show videos.

I am using `PHFetchOptions` to fetch `PHAssets` from Photos library. Also I have provided a predicate to fetch only the photos. Below is my code:

```swift
let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
allPhotosOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == 1")
allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: allPhotosOptions)
```

However I am getting screenshots as well. I do not want to fetch the screenshots. I found that there is a property for that as well. It is called `PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoScreenshot`

I updated the predicate not to fetch screenshots but it doesn't seem to work. So many of my other images are also being filtered which are not screenshots. below is my updated code for predicate

```swift
 allPhotosOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == 1 AND mediaSubtypes != %d", PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoScreenshot.rawValue)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to filter out screenshots using predicates. What I've been doing is first get the `PHAsset`s, then check if `phAsset.mediaSubtypes.contains(.photoScreenshot)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? It seems like saying NOT on a NSPredicate is quite untrivial

```
allPhotosOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(mediaType == 1) AND ((mediaSubtype & %d) != 0)", PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoScreenshot.rawValue)
```

Got this snippet from [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/44133) Apple Developer forums post

Answer (score -1):

Try this, should work for your case:

```
allPhotosOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == \(PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue) AND !((mediaSubtype & \(PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoScreenshot.rawValue)) == \(PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoScreenshot.rawValue))")
```